# How to create a menu item which is not a page

Tags: menus, pages

I have a few pages that contains technical tips.

I would like to group these pages under the title "tips" in the menu bar, but I don't want to make the item "tips" clickable because it does not contain any data.

How do I create a menu item which is not a page, whose sole purpose is to server as a menu parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Appearance » Menus**, is you are using WordPress 3.7+, then from the left, under **Links** area, put your URL and then *name* the link. If you don't want to link the menu to any physical link, then just put a hash (`#`) there.
[image: Custom Menu Link]

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom link and add # as the url